# Is there way to fix the foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I got problem on this, and this is the first time I encounter this error in mysql or even in workbench why if delete the row it shows error of

> Cannot delete or update a parent row a foreign key constraint fails.

I have here my sample screen shot with having error when I deleting the data.

[image: Error]

Comment: This error usually occurs because you are trying to delete a parent record which still has children which are pointing to it.  MySQL is blocking this deletion to avoid broken foreign key relationships.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you for explaining to me, to solved that what should I need to do?

Comment: Show us your table structure (both tables), and maybe add some sample data.  Someone can give you a query which will flush out the offending records.  Also include the SQL which caused the error.

Comment: you need to drop related rows in values_roles table before deleting from evaluation_values